How to retrieve and display notifications in Next.js?
I have my application sending notifications to the SQL server in this format:

Now, I am trying to display all of these notifications (user based) in a dropdown list as below.
//src/components/NotificationDropdown.js/
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { IconButton, Badge, Menu, MenuItem, List, ListItem, ListItemText } from '@mui/material';
import NotificationsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Notifications';
import { useAuthContext } from 'src/contexts/auth-context';

const NotificationDropdown = () => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);
  const [unreadCount, setUnreadCount] = useState(0);
  const { user } = useAuthContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchNotifications = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/notifications/fetchNotifications?userId=${user.id}`);
        if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Failed to fetch notifications');
        const data = await response.json();
        if (data.notifications) {
          setNotifications(data.notifications);
          setUnreadCount(data.notifications.filter(notification => !notification.read).length);
        } else {
          setNotifications([]);
          setUnreadCount(0);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching notifications:', error);
        // Optionally display an error message to the user
      }
    };

    fetchNotifications();
  }, [user.id]); // Assuming user.id is stable and doesn't change

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const markAsRead = (notificationId) => {
    setNotifications(notifications.map(notification => {
      if (notification.id === notificationId) {
        return { ...notification, read: true };
      }
      return notification;
    }));
    setUnreadCount(prevUnreadCount => prevUnreadCount - 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <IconButton color="inherit" onClick={handleClick}>
        <Badge badgeContent={unreadCount} color="error">
          <NotificationsIcon />
        </Badge>
      </IconButton>
      <Menu
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <List>
          {notifications.length > 0 ? (
            notifications.map(notification => (
              <MenuItem key={notification.id} onClick={() => markAsRead(notification.id)}>
                <ListItem>
                  <ListItemText primary={notification.message} />
                </ListItem>
              </MenuItem>
            ))
          ) : (
            <MenuItem>
              <ListItemText primary="No notifications to show!" />
            </MenuItem>
          )}
        </List>
      </Menu>
    </>
  );
};

export default NotificationDropdown;

This is my API to fetch the notifications:
// pages/api/notifications/fetchNotifications.js
import db from 'src/database/db-config';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    const { userId } = req.query;
    if (!userId) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'User ID is required' });
    }

    try {
      const query = 'SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE user_id = ? AND is_read = 0 ORDER BY created_at DESC';
      const notifications = await db.query(query, [userId]);
      res.status(200).json({ notifications });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching notifications:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Server Error', details: error.message });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST']);
    res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
  }
}

And my auth-context to show populate the notifications when the page is loaded:
//src/contexts/auth-context.js
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useReducer, useRef } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const HANDLERS = {
  INITIALIZE: 'INITIALIZE',
  SIGN_IN: 'SIGN_IN',
  SIGN_OUT: 'SIGN_OUT',
  FETCH_NOTIFICATIONS_START: 'FETCH_NOTIFICATIONS_START',
  FETCH_NOTIFICATIONS_SUCCESS: 'FETCH_NOTIFICATIONS_SUCCESS',
  FETCH_NOTIFICATIONS_FAILURE: 'FETCH_NOTIFICATIONS_FAILURE'
};

const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isLoading: true,
  user: null,
  notifications: [],
  isFetchingNotifications: false,
  notificationError: null
};

const handlers = {
  [HANDLERS.FETCH_NOTIFICATIONS_START]: (state) => ({
    ...state,
    isFetchingNotifications: true,
    notificationError: null
  }),
  [HANDLERS.FETCH_NOTIFICATIONS_SUCCESS]: (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    isFetchingNotifications: false,
    notifications: action.payload
  }),
  [HANDLERS.FETCH_NOTIFICATIONS_FAILURE]: (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    isFetchingNotifications: false,
    notificationError: action.payload
  }),
  [HANDLERS.INITIALIZE]: (state, action) => {
    const user = action.payload;

    return {
      ...state,
      ...(
        // if payload (user) is provided, then is authenticated
        user
          ? ({
            isAuthenticated: true,
            isLoading: false,
            user
          })
          : ({
            isLoading: false
          })
      )
    };
  },
  [HANDLERS.SIGN_IN]: (state, action) => {
    const user = action.payload;

    return {
      ...state,
      isAuthenticated: true,
      user: user || null // Ensure user is defined or set to null

    };
  },
  [HANDLERS.SIGN_OUT]: (state) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      isAuthenticated: false,
      user: null
    };
  }
};

const reducer = (state, action) => (
  handlers[action.type] ? handlers[action.type](state, action) : state
);

// The role of this context is to propagate authentication state through the App tree.

export const AuthContext = createContext({ undefined });

export const AuthProvider = (props) => {
  const fetchNotifications = async () => {
    dispatch({ type: HANDLERS.FETCH_NOTIFICATIONS_START });
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/notifications/fetchNotifications', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${window.sessionStorage.getItem('authToken')}`
        }
      });
      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        dispatch({ type: HANDLERS.FETCH_NOTIFICATIONS_SUCCESS, payload: data.notifications });
      } else {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch notifications');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: HANDLERS.FETCH_NOTIFICATIONS_FAILURE, payload: error.message });
    }
  };
  const { children } = props;
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const initialized = useRef(false);

  const initialize = async () => {
    // Prevent from calling twice in development mode with React.StrictMode enabled
    if (initialized.current) {
      return;
    }
  
    initialized.current = true;
  
    let isAuthenticated = false;
  
    try {
      isAuthenticated = window.sessionStorage.getItem('authenticated') === 'true';
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      // If the user is authenticated, fetch user details from the API
      let userId = window.sessionStorage.getItem('userId')
      let compId = window.sessionStorage.getItem('company_id')
     
      if(userId != 'undefined' && userId != null){
        try {
          const response = await fetch('/api/users/'+userId); // Replace '1' with the actual user ID
          if (response.status === 200) {

            let user = await response.json();
            user.company_id = compId;
            dispatch({
              type: HANDLERS.INITIALIZE,
              payload: user,
            });
          } else {
            console.error('Failed to fetch user details from the API');
            // You can decide how to handle the error, e.g., redirect to the login page.
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('API request error:', error);
          // Handle the error as needed.
        }
      }else {
        const user = {
          id: '5e86809283e28b96d2d38537',
          avatar: '/assets/avatars/avatar-anika-visser.png',
          name: 'Anika Visser',
          email: 'anika.visser@devias.io'
        };
    
        dispatch({
          type: HANDLERS.INITIALIZE,
          payload: user,
        });
      }
     
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: HANDLERS.INITIALIZE
      });
    }
  };
  

  useEffect(
    () => {
      initialize();
    },
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    []
  );

  const skip = () => {
    try {
      window.sessionStorage.setItem('authenticated', 'true');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }

    const user = {
      id: '5e86809283e28b96d2d38537',
      avatar: '/assets/avatars/avatar-anika-visser.png',
      name: 'adsada adasd',
      email: 'anika.visser@devias.io'
    };

    dispatch({
      type: HANDLERS.SIGN_IN,
      payload: user
    });
  };



  const signIn = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/users/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
      });
  
      if (response.status === 200) {
        const result = await response.json();
        const user = result.data;
        // user.avatar = '/assets/avatars/avatar-anika-visser.png',
        // user.avatar= '/assets/avatars/avatar-anika-visser.png';
        // user.city = 'Los Angeles';
        // user.country = 'USA';
        // user.jobTitle = 'Senior Developer';
        // user.timezone ='GTM-7';
        // Update the authentication state
        dispatch({
          type: HANDLERS.SIGN_IN,
          payload: user,
        });
        // Store the user's authentication status in sessionStorage
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('authenticated', 'true');
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('userId', user.id);
        let company = user.companies[0];
        let companyId = company.id;
        let companyName = company.name;
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('company_id', companyId);
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('company_name', companyName);
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('companies', JSON.stringify(user.companies));


      } else {
        const errorData = await response.json();
        throw new Error(errorData.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Sign in failed: ' + error.message);
    }
  };
  
  const signUp = async (email, name, password,type, company_id) => {
    try {
      // Replace this with an actual API call to register the user
      const response = await fetch('/api/users/register', {
        
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, name, password , type, company_id}),
      });
      if (response.status === 200) {
        // Registration was successful
        const result = await response.json();
        const user = result.data;
        // user.avatar= '/assets/avatars/avatar-anika-visser.png';
        // user.city = 'Los Angeles';
        // user.country = 'USA';
        // user.jobTitle = 'Senior Developer';
        // user.timezone ='GTM-7';
        // Update the authentication state
        dispatch({
          type: HANDLERS.SIGN_IN,
          payload: user,
        });
  
        // Store the user's authentication status in sessionStorage
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('authenticated', 'true');
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('userId', user.id);
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('company_id', user.company_id);

      } else {
        const errorData = await response.json();
        throw new Error(errorData.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Sign up failed: ' + error.message);
    }
  };
  

  const updateUserDetails = async (details) => {
    let userId = window.sessionStorage.getItem('userId');
    if (userId) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/users/update`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(details)
        });
  
        if (response.status === 200) {
          const updatedUser = { ...state.user, ...details };
          dispatch({
            type: HANDLERS.INITIALIZE,
            payload: updatedUser
          });
        } else if (response.status === 401) {
          console.error('User is not authorized to update details');
        } else {
          console.error('Failed to update user details');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('API request error:', error);
      }
    } else {
      console.error('User ID is not available');
    }
  };
      

  const signOut = () => {

    window.sessionStorage.clear();
    dispatch({
      type: HANDLERS.SIGN_OUT
    });
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...state,
        skip,
        signIn,
        signUp,
        signOut,
        updateUserDetails

      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

AuthProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node
};

export const AuthConsumer = AuthContext.Consumer;

export const useAuthContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useAuthContext must be used within an AuthProvider');
  }
  return context;
};

The issue is, when I load the page, it shows this error message:
5530-32d426282e6bf007.js:1 
 GET https://URL_Removed/api/notifications/fetchNotifications?userId=1 500 (Internal Server Error)
5530-32d426282e6bf007.js:1 Error fetching notifications: Error: Failed to fetch notifications
    at e (5530-32d426282e6bf007.js:1:8123)

The notifications should display in the dropdown.
